# Как хранить статистические данные

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, статистика

Появилась проблема хранения статистических данных. Есть допустим касса интернет магазина, она меняется каждый день по много раз. И вот возникает вопрос, как хранить данные, чтобы можно было узнать размер кассы за определенный период времени(сегодня, вчера, неделя, месяц, за все время). Касса может ставать как больше, так и меньше.
Есть вариант хранить в бд, и записывать каждое поступление и расход, но со временем данных будет ставать очень много, и каждый раз их рассчитывать не будет ли затратно вплане производительности?

Comment: На этот вопрос нет точного ответа. Твоей аналитикой по кассе могут пользоваться раз в день, могут раз в месяц, а могут каждые пять минут. В зависимости от этого применяются разные решения. Если твое приложение пока не страдает от падения производительности - нет смысла заморачиваться.

Comment: кассой пользуются часто, каждые минут 20

Comment: *со временем данных будет ставать очень много* Касса вряд ли способна обслужить более 2-3 клиентов в минуту. Это миллион записей в год. До "очень много" ты просто не доживёшь...

Comment: вопрос как сделать лучше, чтобы можно было проводить аналитику по периодам

Comment: *как хранить данные, чтобы можно было узнать размер кассы за определенный период времени(сегодня, вчера, неделя, месяц, за все время).* По завершении дня считать суточную статистику и класть в отдельную таблицу. За подсчётом требуемой статистики (кроме статистики за текущий день) обращаться туда.

Answer (score 0):

Понятие "очень много данных" - расплывчатое :)
Эта задача точно для БД и запросов по правильно индексированным данным.
И "преждевременная оптимизация" - в этом случае как раз зло.

Вы пишете про "раз в 20мин" использования, при 12 часовом рабочем дне, это всего 36 записей => 13к записей за год. Это совсем не "много данных" :)
Кладите в БД. При такой скорости накопления данных, у вас будет полно времени на эксперименты по дальнейшей "оптимизации"